# .flv videos only play audio without image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player, flv

I downloaded a pack of about 50 `.flv` videos, most work just fine on any software that plays `.flv`, but some only play audio without video. I use Ubuntu 10.04 as main OS but also tried on Windows and had the same problem. I tried VLC `v1.2` and latest, non worked.

I've tried converting the `.flv`s to `.avi`s with ffmpeg, and the `.avi`s play fine but the quality sucks, and it took a lot of time to convert so I don't want to image how much it would take to convert it without quality loss.

Lastly, I installed this on Linux: [DesktopPlayerAir](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/browser/trunk/as3/desktopplayer.air?rev=88).

This player can play all the videos with sound and image, so I don't think the VLC can't play the videos because of a codec. But there's a problem, this player has no extra features, not even a playlist and I really need a playlist. I think this player works for all the videos because it makes uses of flash player core.

Does someone knows a similar video player for Linux that will play `.flv` videos and has a playlist feature?

Comment: Use Windows Media Player with K-Lite codec pack, it has playlist support. (For Windows)

Comment: You tried VLC for Linux and VLC for Windows and it didn't work, that's correct? Have you tried other player besides VLC?

Comment: Can you upload and provide a link to one of those FLV files so we can determine the audio and video codecs? Or can you determine those yourself using http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MediaInfo or http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Gspot ?

Comment: OP, can you post the codec information of the problematic videos?

Since you have VLC, you can get the codec info by CTRL+J

Comment: Can you post the command you used for ffmpeg? If you used the default settings that could be why the quality sucked - for some reason the ffmpeg defaults are completely pants.

Answer (score 1):

VLC has a playlist and [can play flash videos](http://wiki.videolan.org/Flash_Video). It may be the case that the support for certain formats is not included in the binary package that is shipped with Ubuntu. You can either look for a Ubuntu package that has support for ffmpeg (libformat) and win32codecs or you can [build VLC from source](http://wiki.videolan.org/Category:Building) and include support for the codecs that you want (step 4).

Answer (score 0):

[Totem](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/totem/) is the default video player in Ubuntu, it plays .flv videos (amongst many other formats, it can even play a DVD .iso file!), it has a playlist feature, and when it encounters a file with a supported but not present codec it displays a dialog offering to install it.